# Installing google app data on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine

I am having an python application with it's database on google app. I have downloaded data from google app but i dont know how to install it on localhost, i dont know the exact commands. I am new to python and google app. Please tell me if any more info is needed...

Comment: Hav you tried following this? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/helloworld

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the bulkloader upload process, specifying your local server as the upload target.